# Adding beans breaks Spring Configuration

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

**EDIT 1:**

I'm currently calling this from a Main class like so:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringAppConfig.class);
        DataSource dSource = ctx.getBean(DataSource.class);
        System.out.println(dSource.getClass().toString());

        if (dSource instanceof Log4jdbcProxyDataSource)
        {
            Log4jdbcProxyDataSource log4jdbcProxyDataSource = (Log4jdbcProxyDataSource) dSource;
            Object lf = log4jdbcProxyDataSource.getLogFormatter();
            System.out.println(lf.getClass().toString());
        }

        System.exit(0);
}
```

}

**Original:**

Code follows after explanation:

I have a Spring application with a JavaConfig, call it the primary app, that imports another Spring JavaConfig class from a library.  This imported JavaConfig is supposed to wrap any DataSource created in the primary app with an Aspect, which has an autowired LogDelegator.

As long as the primary app contains only a DataSource, everything works.  But as soon as I add an EntityManager to the primary app, I get a nested IllegalArgumentException saying that the LogDelegator is null.

Primary App's Config:

```
@Configuration
@Import(MonitoringConfig.class)
public class SpringAppConfig
{
   @Bean
   public DataSource dataSource()
   {
      EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
      EmbeddedDatabase db = builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).build();
      return db;        
   }
}
```

Imported Library Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSpringConfigured
public class MonitoringConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
   @Bean
   public LogDelegator logDelegator()
   {
      return new LogDelegator();
   }

   @Bean
   public ConfigurationAspect configurationAspect()
   {
      return Aspects.aspectOf(ConfigurationAspect.class);
   }
}
```

The Aspect:

```
@Configurable
public aspect ConfigurationAspect
{
   @Autowired
   LogDelegator logDelegator;

   Object around() : execution(public DataSource (@Configuration *).*(..)) {

   Object ret = proceed();
   if (ret instanceof DataSource) {
      Log4jdbcProxyDataSource dataSource = new Log4jdbcProxyDataSource((DataSource) ret);
      dataSource.setLogFormatter(logDelegator);
      return dataSource;
   } else {
      return ret;
   }

}
```

This code works great until I add the following,

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory()
{
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
    vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.H2);
    vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

    return factory;
}


@Bean
public EntityManager entityManager()
{
    return entityManagerFactory().getObject().createEntityManager();
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager()
{
    JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    return jpaTransactionManager;
}
```

and then I get:
**java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class SpringAppConfig: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [publ
ic org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean com.fl.sas.configurable.config.SpringAppConfig.entityManagerFactory()] threw exception; ne
sted exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class SpringAppConfig: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public
javax.sql.DataSource SpringAppConfig.dataSource()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: log4j
dbc: logDelegator cannot be null.**

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you specify to which Config class did you add the entitymanager? MonitoringConfig or SpringAppConfig. Also, how are these config classes being loaded? who's bootstraping the application context?

Comment: Sure.  The EntityManager and other code was added to SpringAppConfig.  In this simple example, a Main class is bootstrapping the applicationcontext, although if I ever get it working it will be in a Spring MVC app.

Comment: Seems aspect is created after call `datasource()`. try settings a `@Depends(value="configurationAspect")` on `datasource()`

Comment: That does it.  Add the answer and I'll give the credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add
@Depends(value="configurationAspect") on dataSource()

Luca Basso Ricci answered the question.  If he ever adds the answer, I'll give him the credit.  :)